# How to run program in background and cater for scenario where window is closed?

Tags: windows, ms-dos

To run program in background I use :

```
START /B my.exe
```

But when I close the command line the process ceases to run. How can run program in background from command line and continue to run if command window is closed ?

Comment: You can't. Why not just run `my.exe` directly from the command line instead of using `start`?

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference:

- if the `my.exe` is a command line tool, then `START /B my.exe` is equivalent to `my.exe` therefore `my.exe` will be killed if corresponding `cmd` window is closed;
- if the `my.exe` is a graphical user interface (GUI) application, then `my.exe` should keep running regardless of corresponding `cmd` window is closed.

You could check the difference using next example (note that `cscript.exe` is a command line tool whilst `wscript.exe` is a GUI application):

```
start "" /B cscript 923692.vbs
```

in opposite to

```
start "" /B wscript 923692.vbs
```

Create a sample `923692.vbs` script as follows (or use another semi-endless one):

```
Dim WshShell, BtnCode
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
  BtnCode = WshShell.Popup( _
    WScript.ScriptName & vbNewLine & "Exit script?" _
    , 5 _
    , WScript.FullName _
    , vbOKCancel + vbQuestion)
  If BtnCode = vbOK Then Exit Do 
  Wscript.Sleep 15000
Loop
```

Read `start` [command reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx) for the `/B` switch meaning.